# Estimate cloudbase height

Tags: clouds

I am trying to estimate cloudbase height using calculations from my weather station temperature/humidity, by calculating those two variables I can get estimated cloudbase height but what puzzles me now is inversion layers and temperature at different heights.

I know grib and grib2 files contain those data but I can't seem to figure out how to pull that data in Java even though I tried like every possible library.

Is there any other way I can accurately estimate cloudbase levels by using some API which gives temperature by height for given latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, you can't get cloudbase height without 3D data. You can do that using radiosondes. However, if your weather station has a [ceilometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceilometer), then you don't actually need many calculations. However, they are usually quite expensive.

If you want a real rough calculation, you can just use the [Lifted Condensation Level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifted_condensation_level), which is more valid estimate during the day than at night.

Note on the grib files: They may not always have all of the variables. For example, the WAVE ocean model (see [NCEP NOMADS](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/)) won't have cloud base, because it is in fact for oceans. However, what you can do is use models like the [GFS](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/), which tell you what model levels have clouds, and then find the height of the lowest level that has cloud cover. It will take some programming though.

Answer (score 4):

From atmospheric soundings. For my area:

http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?TYPE=GIF%3ASTUVE&TIME=current&STNM=60018

Selection from map:

http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html

A how-tos:
http://www.csun.edu/~hmc60533/CSUN_103/weather_exercises/soundings/smog_and_inversions/Understanding%20Stuve_v3.htm

https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/courses/atsc201/A201Resources/SoundingTutorial1/SoundingTutorial1Readings.html

Search "Lifting condensation level stüve (or stuve) diagram". The LCL is the level at which a rising package condensates, aka cloud base.

I once had to learn them, but i largely forgot the details, please don't corner me :-) And maybe there are more modern techniques.